# blackberry device application is working on blackberry playbook tablet?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

hi all blackberry device application is working on blackberry playbook tablet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry playbook is totally different than Blackberry Smartphone. For application development current Blackberry Playbook comes with ADOBE AIR SDK . In future they will support (some articles says that) both Android and JavaME  apps . As of now J2ME applications will not work on Blackberry Playbook.

Please read more about it at http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/adobe.jsp

http://press.rim.com/release.jsp?id=4935